# Dual Axis Graphs - Reporting Services 2005

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reportingservices-2005

I have a need to output a graph in reporting services 2005 with 2 Y axises.  It does not appear that this is possible in RS2005 and I have no idea what options may be available to me.  It sounds like RS2008 may solve this issue, but I do not believe that is in the cards for me.  What other options might I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Dundas Reporting in our SSRS 2005.  it does cost, but brings a lot of value.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible - so say MSFT

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/b6389cb5-7a54-44bc-aa0b-f88c03a9704e/